Catch-up time-lapse buffering and lag issues while working with FFpyplayer frames and QPixmap with a UDP stream in MPEG-TS format
I am trying to build from the code found in this post for my use case. However, I'm having trouble with python FFpyPlayer; with traditional ffplay, I don't have these kinds of issues. When running my application, I notice a catch-up time-lapse buffering effect, where the video playback speeds up considerably and then returns to normal speed. On some videos I have seen somewhat of a stutter or lag. I am using ffpyplayer to handle video playback from udp stream within a background thread with the frames. Not sure where or how, but I believe the issue arises when retrieving and displaying frames using PyQt's QPixmap. Below is the command used to send udp stream using ffmpeg with this stock video:
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i .\2099536-hd_1920_1080_30fps.mp4 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:51234?localaddr=127.0.0.1

And here is ffplay command that runs with no problem:
ffplay udp://127.0.0.1:51234

Here is an example code that uses the ffpyplay to display it with the issues mentioned:
from PyQt6 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
import time
from threading import Thread

class VideoDisplayWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.player = None
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.video_frame_widget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.video_frame_widget)
        self.frame_rate = 30

        self.latest_frame = QtGui.QPixmap()

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setTimerType(QtCore.Qt.TimerType.PreciseTimer)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrameSlot)
        self.timer.start(int(1000.0/self.frame_rate))

        self.play()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def play(self):
        play_thread = Thread(target=self._play, daemon=True)
        play_thread.start()
    
    def _play(self):
        player = MediaPlayer("udp://127.0.0.1:51234")
        val = ''
        while val != 'eof':
            frame, val = player.get_frame()
            if val != 'eof' and frame is not None:
                img, t = frame
                # display img
                w = img.get_size()[0] 
                h = img.get_size()[1]
                data = img.to_bytearray()[0]

                qimage = QtGui.QImage(data, w, h, QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_RGB888)
                self.latest_frame = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
                time.sleep(0.001)
    
    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        self.video_frame_widget.setPixmap(self.latest_frame)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_port = 51234
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    player = VideoDisplayWidget()
    player.show()

    exit(app.exec())

Here is a code block adapted from this post that works with no issues with ffpyplay using opencv:
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
import time
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import cv2

player = MediaPlayer("udp://127.0.0.1:51234")
val = ''
while val != 'eof':
    frame, val = player.get_frame()
    if val != 'eof' and frame is not None:
        img, t = frame
        # display img
        w = img.get_size()[0] 
        h = img.get_size()[1]
        arr = np.uint8(np.array(img.to_bytearray()[0]).reshape(h,w,3)) # h - height of frame, w - width of frame, 3 - number of channels in frame
        arr = cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        
        cv2.imshow('test', arr)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

Is there a specific setting or parameter I should be adjusting with ffpyplay and/or pyqt to prevent this catch-up time-lapse buffering effect?

Well, for starters, QPixmap is not considered thread safe, so you should never create a QPixmap in a thread that is not the QApplication one unless you really know what you're doing: at the very least, you should only store the QImage and eventually use fromImage() in the main thread when calling setPixmap(). Then, you must remember that the python GIL prevents proper concurrency, and doing a CPU-bound computation (including recreating an image) in a separate thread will never improve performance: creating a QImage from a data stream in a separate thread won't be more effective »

» than doing it (when actually needed) in the main thread. Since you're not using signals, but just updating the UI only based on the "last" frame data, it would be more effective to just store that "last frame data" (possibly as a copy) and eventually convert it into a QImage/QPixmap only when required (which is, when the UI loop retakes control and QTimer finally times out). This won't solve all your issues, but, at the very least, should improve performance and prevent "video jittering" to some level.

@musicamante Do you have experience with qasync? Would that be something to try out with this?

No, never used it, but I don't really think that would help much. It provides better control to thread switching, but the computing performance is unchanged, meaning that what written above will still remain: if the issue is caused by an instruction that requires time to compute, async will be of no help. So, the first step is understanding if the delay is caused by computation issues, and if it is, then your only option is to switch to multiprocessing. Note that I don't know the underlying behavior of get_frame(), but you may consider adding a very small sleep() at every iteration.
